# Найти пересечение

Tags: mysql, алгоритм

Всем доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с проблема поиска пересечений в таблице.

Допустим, есть две сущности (называю их классы) и их набор признаков (набор признаков - просто множество чисел). Нужно определить пересекаются ли классы (если пересеклись хотя бы по одному признаку - значит пересекаются) и сколько классов пересеклось.

Вообще задача стоит найти распределение по частоте пересечений. Т.е. нужно найти сколько раз встречается пересечение двух классов, трёх и т.д.

Для начала хочется вообще понять, как находить пересечение.

Таблица выглядит примерно так:

```
+---------+---------+
|  Class  |  mark   |
+---------+---------+
|       А |       1 |
|       А |       2 |
|       А |       3 |
|       В |       2 |
|       В |       3 |
|       В |       4 |
|       С |       3 |
|       С |       1 |
|       D |       6 |
+---------+---------+
```

Так, например в этой таблице все три класса пересекаются, значит есть пересечение степени 3. Так же, каждый из классов пересекается с остальными попарно - есть 3 пересечения степени 2. И есть еще непересекающийся ни с кем класс D => есть 1 пересечение степени 1.

**UPDATE:**
Несколько более сложный пример, когда

```
create table t1 (Class text, mark int);
insert into t1 values 
('A', 1),
('A', 2),
('A', 3), 
('A', 7), 
('A', 8), 
('B', 2),
('B', 3),
('B', 4),
('B', 7),
('B', 8),
('C', 3),
('C', 1),
('D', 6);
```

Тут трижды пересекаются классы "А" и "В" по признакам {2, 7, 8}. Так вот это все одно пересечение степени 2 (просто по трем признакам), а не 3 пересечения.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7feab/1

Comment: Странная таблица. По идее, тут надо граф строить, и куда-то его дампать. Кроме того, пересечений степени 1 тут четыре, так как они тривиальные. Или вместо пересечения тут "связное множество"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, это вам будет чем-то полезно. Так можно узнать перечения по номеру признака

```
create table t1 (Class text, mark int);
insert into t1 values 
('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('A', 3), 
('B', 2), ('B', 3), ('B', 4),
('C', 3), ('C', 1),
('D', 6);
select mark, count(Class) c, group_concat(Class) 
   from t1 
   group by mark 
   order by c desc
```

result

```
mark   c   group_concat(Class)
3      3   A,B,C
1      2   A,C
2      2   A,B
4      1   B
6      1   D
```

**UPDATE** А  вот так сразу получить статистику

```
select c, count(c) 
   from 
    (select distinct count(Class) c, group_concat(Class) g 
       from t1 
     group by mark) as temp
group by c
order by c desc
```

result

```
c    count(c)
3    1
2    2
1    2
```

Comment: а нет инфомации о том что в таблице лишь два поля. сказано выглядит примерно так

Comment: это же тест, предполагаю, что и таблица не называется t1 или table :)

Comment: Мне кажется или здесь `join` можно смело выкинуть? Он же ничего полезного не делает

Comment: @BOPOH при моих знаниях, это запросто, но не получилось. я сейчас попробую на sqlfiddle закинуть, если покажете как, буду признателен

Comment: @BOPOH  закинул http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8b6c/11

Comment: @splash58, так просто: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8b6c/12 Я еще `group_concat` из примера убрал, т.к. он не используется, но можно и с ним было

Comment: Кажется, что пересечений степени "1" должно быть лишь одно - в пересечении лишь один класс "D"

Comment: не, B 4 - еще одно

Comment: @BOPOH  да, это я затупил, я как ее решал последовательно, так про нее и думаю, во втором случае действительно половина не нужнаю Там и ордер во внутреннем запросе не нужен

Comment: @Stas0n В первом результате все хорошо видно. Второй это я уже для статистики придумывал

Comment: @splash58, пересечение степени 1 - это когда в пересечении лишь одно множество лежит. Признак 4 принадлежит классу "В", который по своим другим признакам пересекается с другими классами.     Может, такая формулировка будет понятнее: степень пересечения определяется количеством пересекающихся классов. А наличие или отсутствие пересечения определяется тем, пересекаются ли признаки классов или нет. Не нужно рассматривать  сколько классов "претендуют" на признак.

Comment: @splash58, так `join` можно и из первого запроса удалять - он там не нужен, т.к. на результат не влияет

Comment: @Stas0n  не понимаю логики, тогда А,Б,С попав в тройку не должны попадать в двойку?

Comment: Видимо, плохо объяснил.. Степень пересечения определяется количество пересекающися классов. В нашем примере три класса пересеклись по признаку "3". Больше тройных пересечений нет. Двойные пересечения есть у классов "А" и "В" - по признаку "2" и у классов "А"и "С" - по признаку "1". Итого 2 пересечения со степенью 2. Целиком ни с кем не пересекаясь есть только 1 класс - "D"

Comment: @BOPOH замечательная штука sql. Уже качаю книжку :)

Comment: @Stas0n  По признаку "3" - пересечение трех классов. Про признаку "4" что ? Просто забиваем?  Теперь от классов: А попадает в 3е перечечение по 3 и в 2е  - по 1,2. D - в одинарное по 6. Почему же В не попадает в одинарное по четыре. У меня не складывается

Comment: @splash58, виноват, запутался сам трижды. Все верно Вы написали. Просто пример несколько неудачный. Допустим, у нас усложнился пример (дописал в описании топика). Там трижды пересекаются классы "А" и "В" по признакам {2, 7, 8}. Так вот это все одно пересечение степени 2, а не 3 пересечения.

Comment: @splash58, опять не совсем то: пересечений степени 2 набралось 4 штуки с использованием скрипта, а должно быть 2, так как есть 3 пересечения классов "А" и "В" по признакам {2, 7, 8} - такие вещи нужно типа объединять - как бы одно пересечение по трем признакам. Кажется, это из твоего первого запроса можно сделать.. пока думаю

Comment: Это он count'ы подсчитал. смотрите теперь. Я только так смог

Comment: @Stas0n  поменял на проще. Надо было давно никому не нужный mark выбросить из select

Answer (score 1):

вот набросал примерно. если бы был дам Вашей таблицы, запрос был бы более точным

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id in (SELECT mark
       FROM table
       WHERE Class = 'A')
  AND id in (SELECT mark
       FROM table
       WHERE Class = 'B')
```

Comment: предположил что поле **id** существует. так как это не сказано

Comment: нет, в таблице всего два поля..

Comment: ну ок, значит мое решение не подходит. Такие моменты обычно исправляет дамп таблици. так как в условии сказано примерно так выглядит.